# Corel Painter on Wine

Tags: wine

I have a copy of Corel Painter left over from my Windows/Mac days and wonder if anyone can attest to using Painter under Wine? I just had a look at [MyPaint](http://mypaint.intilinux.com) and will install it regardless, but I'm really used to Painter (interface, workflow, etc.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many opinions and tests of programs in Wine on the WineHQ AppDB. According to the AppDB, all three versions tested are "garbage", which means that they barely work or not at all. Please refer to thetest results linked at http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9119 for more details.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the time saver ;-) ArtRage checks out as GOLD! That's fantastic, simple program but very effective and my favorite as well.

Comment: You are most certainly welcome.